# Horizontally paginate through sets of blog posts?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, query

I have my posts set up like this:

[image]

I would like users to scroll through the posts using the left and right arrows. So when users click on the right arrow, for example, the next six posts would slide into view horizontally.

I know how to pull the main query of posts and set the posts per page to six, but how would I get those posts to work with the pagination?

Comment: I haven't done this before, but my logic tells me that you will need some kind of jquery integration here of some sort, may be something like a slider script or infinite scroll type of script.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Instead of using a slider, do you think an AJAX style pagination solution like this work?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983244/simple-wordpress-ajax-pagination ?

Comment: I ask because if the slider is only needed for the 'sliding' effect, then it's not really needed. I'm perfectly fine with having the next set of posts fade into view instead.

Comment: My ajax and jquery skills are quite lacking, but I would suggest that you try something like that.